# Limit of this function as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: limits, approximation-theory

I was interested in approximating $\log x$ without using the $\log$ function, specifically for values of $x \in [1, e]$, and I got this monster of a function:

$$\left( \frac{x-1}{e-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{ \left( \frac{1}{e-1} \right) \left( \frac{x-1}{e-1}\right)^{1/e} +1}}$$ 
It works as an approximation for $\log x$, very well I might add - the maximum error for $x \in [1, e]$ is ~$.00165...$. But this function is not equivalent to $\log x$, and that error $E \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, and this is because that function approaches a value. Or appears to, anyway. It could diverge to $-\infty$. 
So what is the limit of this function? And how would I go about finding that? I would guess it approaches $1$, but I don't know how to prove it.
For readability's sake, I'll rewrite it like this:
$a = 1/e$
$b= 1/(e-1)$
$z= b(x-1)$
$$f(x) = z^{ \frac{1}{ b \ z^a  +1}}$$

Comment: A decent way to write an approximation of $\log$ is to make a high-accuracy approximation of it on $[1-\delta,1+\delta]$ for some $\delta>0$, call this $g$. Then define your approximation as $f(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) & x \in [1-\delta,1+\delta] \\ -f(1/x) & x \in (0,1-\delta) \\ f(x/e)+1 & x \in (1+\delta,\infty) \end{cases}$.

Comment: That said, are you now just interested in this function for its own sake?

Comment: Yeah, for it's own sake. I'm interested in what this function here converges to; it has a maximum at $x$~$82$, and then appears to decrease monotonically after that. And thank you for that format!

Comment: That is the cases environment. Outside of MathJax you can get it with the amsmath package. It can also be imitated using the array environment in vanilla LaTeX (the trick being "\left \{ ... \right .")

Comment: It would simplify the appearance (and the analysis) if you substituted $z = \frac{x-1}{e-1}$.  Note that as $x\to \infty$, one has $z\to \infty$ (and conversely).

Comment: You have essentially $z^{1/(z^{1/e}+1)}$ (up to some constant factors). The exponent is going to $0$ while the base is going to $\infty$, so this is a L'Hospital type situation. It appears that in this case the exponent goes to zero fast enough that the overall limit is $1$.

Comment: @hardmath Changed, thank you!